# Expanding X_train to attain a shape of (batch_size,width,height,colour_channels)

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, conv-neural-network

I have made a Music Genre Classification Convolutional NN Model in Tensorflow and I face a issue:

I have 999 music Spectrogram images in my X and also have appropriate labels(y). The images are of size (128,1293).
When I check the shape of X it shows me (999,),which signifies number of images ; however I wish to expand X to include the dimensions of the image(1 color channel) to (999,128,1293,1) to feed into my CNN.

[image]

I read somewhere you can do it by cv2.resize() , but I am unsure of that method. Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Comment: what is a type of X ? Is it tensor ?

Comment: X is a pandas Series